# Algorithm crosses upper margin of the page

Tags: vertical-alignment, algorithmic

When does the latex algorithm cross the top-margin of the page? I searched a lot in the web, and tried with --`floatsep, textfloatsep` and `intextsep` but looks like nothing solved my problem so far.
Any quick suggestion will be greatly appreciated. My code is attached below.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\pdfpagewidth 8.5in
\pdfpageheight 11in
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}        
\begin{algorithm}[!t]
        \caption{Candidate Score Normalization Algorithm}
        \label{algo2}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{NORMALIZE}{$R$}

        \For{CandidateSearchTerm $t$ $\in$ $R.keys$}
        \State $R[t] \gets 1-\frac{position(t)}{size(R)}$
        \EndFor
        \State \textbf{return} $R$ 
        \EndProcedure
        \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The code is pretty simple, but not sure why it shows that behavior.

Comment: The extended execution can be found here (http://latex.informatik.uni-halle.de/latex-online/temp/olatex_1676239_lsxYMfHPUADp.png)

Comment: You can execute this code (http://pastebin.com/SFtBLeiM) here (http://latex.informatik.uni-halle.de/latex-online/latex.php) to see the problem.

Comment: Please post the code which demonstrates the problem in the question rather than as an external link  You can always use the [`lipsum`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) package to automatically generate blind text.  What exactly is the problem and what would you like changed to "fix" things?  I see that the algorithm caption is slightly higher than the first line  of the second column but using `\usepackage[showframes]{geomery}` you can see that the algorithm does not extend into any margins.  You may find things improved by using `[htbp]` for float placement rather than `[!t]`.

Comment: "algorithm caption is slightly higher than the first line of the second column"-- that is the problem. The algorithm top should be aligned with the top of the second column. How can I do that?

Comment: The [htbp] option did not help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced. The algorithm doesn't cross over the upper-margin.

Answer (score 1):

The caption positioning is thrown off by the horizontal rule. You can improve it by adding a strut:

```
    \caption{\strut Candidate Score Normalization Algorithm}
```

[image]

compare with the original

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\pdfpagewidth 8.5in
\pdfpageheight 11in
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}        
\begin{algorithm}[!t]
        \caption{Candidate Score Normalization Algorithm}
        \label{algo2}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{NORMALIZE}{$R$}

        \For{CandidateSearchTerm $t$ $\in$ $R.keys$}
        \State $R[t] \gets 1-\frac{position(t)}{size(R)}$
        \EndFor
        \State \textbf{return} $R$ 
        \EndProcedure
        \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can push down the rule by restyling the float (and defining a new style based on `ruled`):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\pdfpagewidth 8.5in
\pdfpageheight 11in

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}% just for the example

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@betterruled{%
  \def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{\vspace*{5pt}\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\floatstyle{betterruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\caption{Candidate Score Normalization Algorithm\label{algo2}}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{NORMALIZE}{$R$}

    \For{CandidateSearchTerm $t$ $\in$ $R.keys$}
      \State $R[t] \gets 1-\frac{position(t)}{size(R)}$
    \EndFor
    \State \textbf{return} $R$ 
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

I added a vertical space by 5pt: 2+2 for the space around the top rule, 0.8 for the rule thickness and 0.2 more for the difference between ascenders. The rules around the text are produced by `showframe`, they'll disappear as soon as you remove the call to it: I used it for making a better visual comparison.

[image]

Actually, the `algorithm` environment *doesn't* cross the top margin: if I remove the `\restylefloat` line, we get the default result. It's the first line in the right column that doesn't go up to the margin.

[image]